# Interpret SQL ID in hanganalyze report oracle

Tags: oracle, trace

I am using oracle database 19c. I need help in understanding the current **sql_id** field in the hanganalyze trace. Generally **sql_id** has alphanumeric values like **bhi12gxhrpqsj** to identify a particular sql statement. But here, there is 10 digit numeric value. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

**Oradebug hanganalyze trace output:**

```
    time in wait: 1 min 20 sec
   timeout after: never
         wait id: 2335
        blocking: 1 session
  current sql_id: 3597362520 <<======
    wait history:
```

Comment: This may be hash value of SQL_ID. Refer [this](https://tanelpoder.com/2009/02/22/sql_id-is-just-a-fancy-representation-of-hash-value/), similar to what you are asking.

Comment: Another similar blog [post](https://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/sql-id-in-ADS-trace,4), that might be helpful here.

Comment: In the hang analyze report, it clearly states sql_id and how do we know that it is exactly a hash value?